# discord.py osu stats error: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i'm trying to do a command that displays user stats of a game called osu.
The following is the command:

```py
@client.command()
async def osu(ctx, arg):
    token = "secret token"
    res = requests.get(f"https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?u={arg}&k={token}")

    nickname = res.json()['username']

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Ecco le statistiche di osu.", description=f'Speriamo sia forte lmao', color=discord.Color.orange())
    embed.add_field(name="Nickname", description=nickname)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When i try to use the command i get the following traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "botlinux.py", line 2035, in osu
    nickname = res.json()['username']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "botlinux.py", line 446, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\Aleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Aleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What i'm doing of wrong?
As you can see from the code i get the info from a page, with a JSON structure if i can call it like this.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: What's the output of `print(res.json())`?

Comment: Wow what a quick reply. The output displays correctly the user info.

Comment: No, what's the _exact_ output? Is it a list? According to the error message, it's a list, but you're trying to index it with strings, as if it was a dictionary

Comment: this is the exact output `[{'user_id': '15162649', 'username': 'aleee1', 'join_date': '2019-09-10 19:34:22', 'count300': '239180', 'count100': '71184', 'count50': '12155', 'playcount': '2196', 'ranked_score': '85778421', 'total_score': '452251403', 'pp_rank': '798176', 'level': '41.0368', 'pp_raw': '417.426', 'accuracy': '87.17240905761719', 'count_rank_ss': '0', 'count_rank_ssh': '0', 'count_rank_s': '7', 'count_rank_sh': '0', 'count_rank_a': '14', 'country': 'IT', 'total_seconds_played': '139388', 'pp_country_rank': '9050', 'events': []}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was shown in the comments, `res.json()` returned a `list` (what it will return depends entirely on the API), which cannot be indexed with strings, like `nickname = res.json()['username']`.

However, the list contains one dictionary, which is presumably what you're looking for. So you can simply extract it and then retrieve its values:

```
res = requests.get(f"https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?u={arg}&k={token}")

dictionary, = res.json()  # extract the dictionary

nickname = dictionary['username']
gioca_da = dictionary['join_date']
...
```

Comment: The `,` after `dictionary` is an typing error or is right like this?

Comment: It's supposed to be like this, yes: it means unpacking an iterable with exactly one element. You can unpack a list of 2 elements like this: `a, b = [1, 2]`, where `a == 1 and b == 2`; your list contains exactly one element, so you can unpack it like this: `a, = [1]`, where `a == 1`. If you write `a = [1]`, you'll assign the whole list to `a`.